# Loading/Executing CLR 2.0 assemblies in CLR 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, clr4.0

Can the CLR 4.0 execute CLR 2.0 IL without the need for source code recompilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [nice article](http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/06/07/in-process-side-by-side-part-2-common-in-proc-sxs-scenarios.aspx) explaining different scenarios. In the comments section there's a [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876(VS.100).aspx) which provides further information.